# exception occured while sending ,javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: java, email

This has come to only for (smtp.office365.com ) SMTP.

```
public int sendEmail(String fromName,String fromAddress,ArrayList toAddressList ,ArrayList ccAddressList,ArrayList bccAddressList,String subject,String message,String SmtpServerIP,String smtpUserName,String smtpPassword, ArrayList<String>  attachmentFilePath ){
        SMTP_HOST_NAME=SmtpServerIP;
        SMTP_AUTH_USER=smtpUserName;
        SMTP_AUTH_PWD=smtpPassword;
        String emailmultipart="true";
        String smtpHost=SmtpServerIP;
        //System.out.println("SmtpServerIP"+SmtpServerIP);

        System.out.println("fromName :"+fromName+":SmtpServerIP:"+SmtpServerIP+":smtpPassword:"+smtpPassword+":smtpUserName:"+smtpUserName);
        boolean debug = false;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true"); 
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        if(smtpHost==null){
          return -99; 
        }
        if(smtpHost.length()>0){
          //props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
          props.setProperty("mail.host", smtpHost);
         }
        else
        { 
          return 1; 
        }//Error No SmtpHost name Found.
       /* if(smtpUserName!=null && smtpUserName.length()>0){
            props.setProperty("mail.user", smtpUserName);
        }
        if(smtpPassword!=null && smtpPassword.length()>0){
            props.setProperty("mail.password", smtpPassword);
        }*/
        Session session=null;

        if(smtpUserName!=null && smtpUserName.length()>0&&smtpPassword!=null && smtpPassword.length()>0){
            System.out.println("smtpUserName111111111111111"+smtpUserName);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        }else{
            System.out.println("smtpUserName2222222222222222"+smtpUserName);
            session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);  
        }
        session.setDebug(debug);
        try{
            //System.out.println("toAddressList.size()"+toAddressList.size());
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(fromAddress,fromName);
            String msgSubject=subject;
            msg.setFrom(from);
            msg.setSubject(msgSubject);
            msg.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            //msg.setSentDate(new Date(2005,9,12));

            //for adding TO address list.
            if(toAddressList.size()>0){
              Address toAddresses[]= new InternetAddress[toAddressList.size()];      
              toAddresses=getAddresses(toAddressList);
              //System.out.println(" toAddresses |||"+toAddresses);
              msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,toAddresses);

             }
             else{
                 return 2;
             }
            //for adding CC address list.
            if(ccAddressList.size()>0){
              Address ccAddresses[]= new InternetAddress[ccAddressList.size()];      
              ccAddresses=getAddresses(ccAddressList);
              msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,ccAddresses);
            }
            //for adding BCC address list.
            if(bccAddressList.size()>0){
              Address bccAddresses[]= new InternetAddress[bccAddressList.size()];      
              bccAddresses=getAddresses(bccAddressList);
              msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC,bccAddresses);
            }
            if(attachmentFilePath.size()>0){
                //System.out.println("Inside File Attachment attachmentFilePath.length()"+attachmentFilePath.length());
                //File file=new File(attachmentFilePath); 
                //if(file.exists()){
                    msg=attachFileAndMessage(msg,attachmentFilePath,message);
                //}else{
                  //  System.out.println("File does Not exists.");  
                  //  return 3;
                //}
            }
           // Transport.send(msg);
            msg.saveChanges(); // implicit with send()
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            //System.out.println("smtpHost :: "+smtpHost+"     smtpUserName ::"+smtpUserName+"       smtpPassword ::"+smtpPassword);
            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

        }
       catch(MessagingException mex){
            mex.printStackTrace();
          String errmsg=mex.getMessage().toString();
          if(errmsg.indexOf("Unknown SMTP host")>-1){
            System.out.println("Invalid SMTP server entry");
            return 101;
          }else if(errmsg.indexOf("Invalid Addresses")>-1){
            System.out.println("Invalid Address entry");
            return 102;
          }              
          System.out.println("Error 1 ::"+mex.getMessage());
          mex.printStackTrace();
          return 4;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Error 2 ::"+e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
          return 5;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem and what's the question?

Comment: this exception is came while sending email: javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Comment: It still means nothing. Update your question with the full exception stack trace and tell us what exactly happens.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have problem here. You auth is empty.

```
Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
```

Try

```
 Authenticator auth = new Authenticator()
    {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);
        }
    };
```

This code works for me. javax.mail v1.5

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String smtpAuthUserName = "YOUR_ADDRES@YOURCOMPANY.COM";
        final String smtpAuthPassword = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
        String emailFrom = "EMAIL_FROM";
        String emailTo   = "EMAIL_TO";
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator()
        {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(smtpAuthUserName, smtpAuthPassword);
            }
        };
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session session = Session.getInstance( properties, authenticator );
        try
        {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFrom));
            InternetAddress[] to = {new InternetAddress(emailTo)};
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
            message.setSubject("PLACE_SUBJECT_HERE");
            message.setText("YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE");
            Transport.send(message);
        }
        catch (MessagingException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are better supposed to explain why this code works for you as the op will want to know why he had his problem and why it now solved

Answer (score 0):

If the error persists even after adding the above code.Please refer to the mail.jar of the project.May be the mail.jar is corrupted for the project.change it with the latest version of mail.jar and check

Comment: I got the same error and is running flawless after adding updated mail.jar

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that this is not a discussion forum. Answers do not have a fixed order, so there is no "above". If you refer to a question or answer you can point to it with a link. Also this should have been a comment on the answer by user SomethingNew. Once you have gained more reputation you will be able to comment on other peoples' posts. Until then focus on providing high quality answers or questions. Please read and understand the help pages to understand how this site works.

Comment: ok.Will do now onwards. But here I saw only one answer.That is why I comment like that

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using an older version of **javax.mail** (1.3.1).  When I switched to a later version (1.4.4), the problem went away.

If you are using Eclipse, you may need to look in the build path which libraries your project is using, not just the external ones that you specified, but also the built-in ones like JavaEE5, etc. which may have an older version of this library inside of them.

You can check the exact version of the library being used by debugging on this statement in your code:  `Session session = Session.getInstance(...`

It will not show you the source code, but will give you directory path of the mail.jar that it's using, and you can open that up to see the version (in the **MANIFEST** file).